# Break a for loop containing an AJAX-type function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am a big noob in Javascript, and this is probably the first of a long series of questions!

Here what I'm trying to do:

I have a folder containing several .txt files called art1.txt, art2.txt, etc. (the total number can vary, this is important).

I am building a script that will extract the text information of every txt files and append them one after another on a web page. Here it is:

```
function init(){

 for (var i=1; ; i++) {

  $(function doAjax (){
    var getArt = {  "method"  : "get", 
                    "url"     : "data/ConstitutionLaw/art" + i +".txt", 
                    "success" : successHandler,
                    "error"   : endLoop
                 };

    $.ajax(getArt);

    function successHandler(data){
        console.log(data);
        var newArt = document.createElement('p');
        newArt.setAttribute('class', "article");
        newArt.innerHTML = data;
        $('#artBody').append(newArt);
        }; //end of successHandler
  }); //end of doAjax

    function endLoop() { /* end the for loop */ };
 }; //end of for
} //end of init
```

At the moment, I execute the function doAjax an infinite number of times, because I don't know how many txt files I have. I want to break the loop if the code doesn't find the file artN.txt (meaning there is no more files in the folder) by executing the endLoop function

I tried to use a if statement after the function doAjax, but problem is it's an asynchronous function and the for loop doesn't wait for doAjax to end before starting another loop.

How could I make the for loop to wait until doAjax is finished to start a new loop?

Also, if you have any suggestions to make the overall less clumsy, please let me know. :)

Thanks for reading!

Comment: change your for loop to a do-while loop and then in error return a false variable.

Comment: You can use recursion.

Comment: You don't must use a infinite loop in this case: you can obtain all files from the server in one request and process the response with Javascript.

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/loops/#the-do-while-loop

Comment: also you're mixing a lot of javascript / jquery.. you can do the newArt line... as `$('#artBody').append('<p class="article">'+data+'</p>');`

Comment: are you using a server-side "back-end" language like php, python, or other? The problem with the $.ajax the way you are calling it is asynchronous. you wont be able to break from the loop that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you accomplish what you want. Although, I would still recommend using a server side scripting language to accomplish this more effectively.

```
function init(){
  var stop = false;

  for(var i=1; ; i++) {
    $.ajax({
      "async"   : false,
      "method"  : "get",
      "url"     : "data/ConstitutionLaw/art" + i +".txt",
    }).success(function(data){
      console.log(data);
      var newArt = document.createElement('p');
      newArt.setAttribute('class', "article");
      newArt.innerHTML = data;
      $('#artBody').append(newArt);
    }).fail(function(){
      stop = true;
    });

    if(stop) {
      break;
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Introduce an ending condition in a do-while loop:

```
function init(){
  var stopLooping = false;

  do {

    $(function doAjax () {
        var getArt = {  "method"  : "get", 
                    "url"     : "data/ConstitutionLaw/art" + i +".txt", 
                    "success" : successHandler,
                    "error"   : endLoop
                 };

        function successHandler(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var newArt = document.createElement('p');
            newArt.setAttribute('class', "article");
            newArt.innerHTML = data;
            $('#artBody').append(newArt);
        }; //end of successHandler

        function endLoop() { 
            stopLooping = true; 
        };

     }); //end of doAjax         

     $.ajax(getArt);

 } while ( !stopLooping );

} //end of init
```

The problem with that code is, that the ajax is running asynchronously and it will issue another x unsuccessful calls until the loop actually stops when returning from the first error handler.